# How can I make bounce effect to listview as in ios

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I need to make bounce effect to my listview in android.ie when I scroll down listview has to scroll beyond its starting point and the come back to its original position
Please help..

Comment: This is generally a bad idea. Implementing overscoll bounce doesn't match Android user's expectations. Plus, it tends not to be implemented well.

Answer (score 2):

as you not posted your code(I think it is also not required as per your question).
So I am giving a [Custom Widget](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-pulltorefresh)

It is custom widget of listview (not that much complicated, just animation is added into it)
use the library for your application.
and also from that in `PullToRefreshActivity` there is 
`mListItems.addFirst("Added after refresh...");` statement just remove it if you want..
(don't worry about activity name or class name
 here target is you got your result)
i.e bounce effect to Listview

 If you satisfy..then Please accept the answer..

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of things in the [`ScrollView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html) API you should be able to override the [`onOverScrolled()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#onOverScrolled%28int,%20int,%20boolean,%20boolean%29) method if you create a custom view that extends the ScrollView class.